# Sublime text 2 find in folder with file extension

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

How do I search in a folder in sublime text 2 with file extension?

My where when I use:

```
*.js
```

searches globally for all js files.

If I try to restrict it to a folder:

```
/project/*.js
```

it matches nothing.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
/project/*.js
```

Try using this:

```
project .js
```

This should match files which have **project** in the path and have a **.js** extension

**EDIT**: The above assumes you're trying to find all the files with .js extension using the Goto Anything feature in Sublime Text.

In case you'd like to search within .js files located within a directory, you can add an Include Filter in the search path:

```
/project,*.js
```

This will search for the text you've entered, limiting the scope to files within **/project** and it's sub-directories having the extension .js.

Reference: [Sublime Text Docs - Search Scope](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html#search-scope)

**EDIT 2**: For Sublime Text 3, refer Simons answer below.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you were asking, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It works for me in Sublime Text 3 too (unlike the other answer).

Comment: me too, it works in sublime3, while Simons answer not works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on ST3 on windows. @SimonEast's answer worked though

Comment: Still works in ST4 :)

Answer (score 27):

godfrzero's answer does not work in Sublime 3 as it actually includes ALL JS files plus ALL files in the project folder.

Instead, you need to specify it similar to how you had it originally...

```
project/*.js
```

Note that there's no leading slash, as that will treat it as an *absolute path* which you won't want in most cases.  To include multiple file types within the folder, I think you need to specify it like this:

```
folder/*.ctp,folder/*.php
```

This will match any of the following files:

```
/app/folder/example.ctp
/app/folder/example.php
/app/folder/subfolder/example.ctp
/app/long/path/folder/subfolder/example.php
```

I know you asked about Sublime 2, but hopefully this helps others (like myself) who are Googling for such advice.

Simon.

Comment: I wanted to do this with an absolute path and it didn't work. I removed the leading slash and it worked perfectly.

Example:

`/home/user/folder/*.rb` does not work
`home/user/folder/*.rb` works

Comment: Note that you've got to use forward slashes, even in Windows, though right-clicking and selecting "Find in Folder" in your sidebar gives you an absolute path with unescaped backslashes (again, in windows). A little unintuitive for me; ymmv.

Comment: This doesn't work. `...\*.css:
    ERROR: Unable to open file`

Comment: The accepted answer actually works in ST3. This too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28818727/2415524

Answer (score 5):

**My Sublime ver**: 3.2.2

Adding to above answers, I was trying to find in all python files starting with **test_** . so this is how I did it.

After pressing Ctrl+Shift+F, in the window.

```
Where : /home/WorkDir/test, test_*.py
```

[image]