# How do I search a text in all the projects in sublime text 2

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

How do I search a text in all the projects in sublime text 2 with only specified extension. For example 'error message' only in files with .js extension

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime text 2 find in folder with file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555791/sublime-text-2-find-in-folder-with-file-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **search for a word or regex in all files**:

`CMD+Shift+F` on Macs to search all files
Specify `*.js` in combination with `,-*/tests/*, -*/build/*` or similar places you don't want to look

---

**jump to a function in your codebase**:
 quickly type the function's name or put your cursor on it, then press `CMD+Optn+Down` to show a small list of possibilities, then use `up/down` and letters to deliminate, optionally press `ESC` to leave the header box, or `ENTER` to enter the file at the function's appearance

**jump to a function in the current file:**
 use `CMD+R` and deliminate, using `ESC` to cancel

**jump to a file:** `CMD+P` or `CMD+T` again using `ESC` or `ENTER` with delimiters

**quickly highlight all occurences of a word:**`CMD+D` or use `CMD+G / CMD+SHIFT+G` to skip around

**fold code for quick file overview:** use `CMD+A` followed by `CMD+KJ` and `CMD+K2` for example

---

fold code and scroll and use the aforementioned `CMD+OPTN+DOWN` to get a good understanding of related files. [Predawn Skin](https://github.com/jamiewilson/predawn#about) looks great with neon green functions :)

Install that with [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) using `CMD+SHIFT+P`

Which reminds me that you can **set your file syntax** using `CMD+SHIFT+P` `"Set Syntax: JavaScript"`

Answer (score 2):

Use Ctrl Shift F which will bring up the global search dialog. You can specify options from there. [image]

Edit: Specify '*.js' in the where. See [Sublime text 2 find in folder with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555791/sublime-text-2-find-in-folder-with-file-extension)

Comment: Specify '*.js' in the where. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555791/sublime-text-2-find-in-folder-with-file-extension