# How to search multiple files of specific file type within Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to search for a string within all *.php files in a certain directory (and its sub-directories) using the Shift + Ctrl + F search dialog.

My guess was to set the search location to:

```
c:\example\*.php
```

but that gives an error:

```
Unable to open c:\example\*.php
```

Is there a way to perform the search I'm hoping to perform?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`C:\example,*.php`

In the `Where:` click `...`, select `Add Folder`, after that select `Add Include Filter`