# Sublime Text 3 - 'Find in Files' in Subdirectory/Subfolder of Project Source Tree

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

## Background

I am working on a project that has a very large source tree.  Since the source tree is large, the 'find in files' functionality of Sublime Text 3 takes quite some time to complete its search.  I know that the symbols for which I am searching will only occur in certain (perhaps multiple) subdirectories of this source tree.

## Question

Is there a way to restrict the 'find in files' functionality of Sublime Text 3 to search multiple (but not all) subdirectories of a project source tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say you have a folder structure like this opened in Sublime Text:

```
root
    other
        bar
        foo
    target
        bar
        foo
```

We want to search in *target*.

1. Open the find panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
2. In the **Where** field, add this filter:

   ```
   target/
   ```
3. Search

The filter means "Search in any files that have a folder named *target* in the path.

You can be more specific by including more of the path, e.g. `target/foo/`. This will search in `root/target/foo/`, but not `root/other/foo/`.

Specify additional subdirectories by separating with commas, e.g. `target/foo/,other/bar/`.

[Official Search and Replace documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)

You'll probably eventually also want to filter by file type. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555791/sublime-text-2-find-in-folder-with-file-extension) for how to do that.