# Sublime Text 3 - Search multiple folders with regex for files in one folder

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to perform a search on all of the files in the `/app/libraries` and `/app/views` folders, but I only want to search within files starting with `App` in the `/app/models` folder.

If I use `/app/libraries, /app/views, /app/models/App*` it gives me:

```
/app/models/App*:
    ERROR: Unable to open file
0 matches
```

If I use `/app/libraries, /app/views, /app/models, App*` it only gives me files starting with `App` in **all** of the folders.

I've tried getting rid of the leading slash `/app/libraries, /app/views, app/models/App*` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084297/3461763), but I get this:

```
Searching 0 files for "search string" (regex, case sensitive)

0 matches
```

Comment: Try replacing `*` with `.*` or `[^/]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew omg. `.*` worked. I think I'm brain dead today. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is that you have been using *wildcard* pattern while you needed a *regex* pattern.

To match any amount of any chars in wildcard patterns, an asterisk is used, but in regex patterns, you may use either `.*` (any 0+ chars other than line break chars) or - if you need to only match `App` as part of the file name (and thus, no more `/` are allowed) - you may use `[^/]*` (zero or more chars other than `/`.

So, use either

```
/app/models/App.*
```

or

```
/app/models/App[^/]*
```